# Convert issues when visiting family (eating)

Tags: kashrut-kosher, conversion-to-judaism

I’m wondering if converts or even just Jews visiting less religious family members or friends have special travel sets of dishes they use when they visit. Is this allowed under the kosher rules?

I would think some type of solution to eat with family would be allowed because even though one converts, many of the duties of maintaining that special bond remain.

Do dish/cooking sets specifically for this exist?

Comment: All the issues surrounding family and eating are a HUGE deal for converts and balei teshuva; every individual solution (such as the "special kosher dishes" idea you cleverly suggest) should be discussed with a rabbi

Comment: Also, realize that for most people in most places, disposable plates and bowls are easy enough to come by; it's the pots, pans, cooking utensils and ovens that prevent most observant Jews from being able to easily consume food made in non-kosher kitchens

Comment: This isn't only about visiting nonreligious. It's about visiting someone on what you believe is a lower level of observance, even if they are religious. I knew a famous rosh yeshiva who was extremely religiously fanatical. He raised his children in that same vein. So much so, that some of them brought their own dishes whenthey visited him!